# Print exponential equation on Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, sympy

I feel like this is a very dumb question, but it's so dumb after an hour of searching I found no example or explanation on how to do what I want to do!

Simply, I have an equation y = a*x^b, where I have the values of a and b inside a list called param (that is, a = param[0] and b = param[1]) through a curve fitting method. I'd want to print it onto my plot so I could have the equation of the fitted curve, sort of in the way Excel does! Here what I have yet :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(xdata,ydata, 'ro', color='red', label='Original Data')
ax.loglog(xdata,ans, '--', color='blue', label='Fitted curve')

ax.text(xdata.mean,ydata.mean,r'$param[0]*x^param[1]$')

ax.set(xlabel='1/dX', ylabel='Erreur L2', title='Erreur L2 en fonction du raffinement')

ax.grid(True)
ax.legend()
```

Which works, until I call `fig.save ()` where it returns a bunch of errors because it disliked the `ax.text` part of the "setting up"

I've tried playing around with this but still, same issues :

(Note, here, `func` is a defined function I used to obtain the fitted parameters)

```
tex = sym.latex(func('x',*param).replace('$',''))
ax.title(r'$f(x) = %s$' %(tex), fontsize=16)
```

and/or

```
x = sym.symbols('x')
equation = sym.printing.latex(param[0]*x**{param[1]})
```

No combination of what I've tried has worked, I'm honestly lost.
Any input into this would be greatly appreciated! :)
Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Here's a pastebin of it, it's quite long! https://pastebin.com/efEY0w09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error code and your code

```
ax.loglog(xdata,ydata, 'ro', color='red', label='Original Data')
ax.loglog(xdata,ans, '--', color='blue', label='Fitted curve')

ax.text(xdata.mean,ydata.mean,r'$param[0]*x^param[1]$')
```

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

It looks like you should replace `xdata.mean` with `xdata.mean()` and do the same with ydata. Assuming that xdata, ydata etc are all numpy arrays.

The error code says you're passing the method itself and not the result of the method.

On a separate note, `plot.text` requires coordinates for the first two inputs (so unless you intend for the mean to be where your equation displays), refer to the help [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)

> matplotlib.pyplot.text
>
> matplotlib.pyplot.text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, withdash=, **kwargs)[source]
>
> Add text to the axes.
>
> Add the text s to the axes at location x, y in data coordinates.

Consider changing `ax.text(xdata.mean(),ydata.mean(),r'$param[0]*x^param[1]$')` to something like `ax.text(0,1,f'{xdata.mean()}*x^{ydata.mean()}')`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the printing of the equation! However it prints "param[0]" instead of its value, any ideas on how I could fix that mixup?

Comment: Just edited the answer to incorporate f-strings for py3..... It looks like you're trying really hard to use latex so you should also look into https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html

Comment: That did it! Thanks a bunch, it's really appreciated :)